# Textract - windows10 - shell error - failed with exit code 127

Tags: python, pypdf, file-not-found, pdfminer, pdftotext

The below code works fine for txt file but doesn't work with pdf files.

```
import textract
text = textract.process(r'C:\Users\Python_files\accounts.txt')
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is in the below code snippet:

```
import textract
path = r'C:\Users\Python_files\accounts.pdf'
text = textract.process(path)
```

The above code results in the following error:

```
ShellError: The command `pdftotext C:\Users\Python_files\accounts.pdf -` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------
```

Comment: Do you have `pdftotext` installed? And does the file actually exist? Something you can do to debug is just run the shell command that failed directly, and see if it works.